# The example of intersection type in typescript official documentation doesn't works

Tags: typescript

The example code of [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) in typescript official documentation doesn't works.

I am learning typescript, and typing the example code of intersection type in to [Playground editor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB5WWAJgHgGIwBOAzlADSIDKyECWAfABTBGkBciBJ5ixNdHarWwBKDl1KIAZFX7ZEAbwBQiVYmGTCyYiAA2UDgAUAhoVjHd+VlGmzhDRAF5FAXwDcKtcDiFEjDTYADoRwgYgwSCzcIoqeamowwH5RpAB0ABbGxADyAO5ghiGByGYAnozBoSIxyvF1aoxaOvqIWZzWIgDalYEAuk6IKVDdRb0e9aoucYhT8d6+-giSPeFIfPY10-GJfut0GVl5BUUlUOU91bETdY3aejZtQnRdPf3Oe9gjoWNbarN-0y0UBAhCQTXurWI7W4tie2A8UyUEF0WShhhKxAQVzUAUIIGgPgqIAARroYBBEGBjABbZAcUiECIAcxqMyUiIiGEIwGMEGQiAAMnAmUzjKT+bU1LphYwqbT6VBGWAWRwAG5wGBYBFKJEo4hQgDCSzgumQQpFJXC1MCptpYCgUPNovF2NU0qZsppyE21w0JuQqXdjAABgAJZC6aUUACSAHJqYgACQKOXIFypYMicYAxEBRAAKxgCecaAw2FlyFyiHRJAQjFjACki7GRBQjWBMaanSVUpUoHAzsUs0pC9TAzLR6lU8OgA) , and i got some error tips. as a picture shows below:

[image]

how to fix them?

----- Update Again ------

The recommended one is as below, more details can find in the comments!

```js
function extend<First extends object, Second extends object>(first: First, second: Second): First & Second {
    const result: Partial<First & Second> = {};
    for (const prop in first) {
        if (first.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            (result as unknown as First)[prop] = first[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in second) {
        if (second.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            (result as unknown as Second)[prop] = second[prop];
        }
    }
    return result as unknown as First & Second;
}

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}

interface Loggable {
    log(name: string): void;
}

class ConsoleLogger implements Loggable {
    log(name: string) {
        console.log(`Hello, I'm ${name}.`);
    }
}

const jim = extend(new Person('Jim'), ConsoleLogger.prototype);
jim.log(jim.name);
```

Comment: This is the most likely best way to approach the issue. First of all the `extends Object` - they do make the most sense here. Only Objects can be extended, not primitive types (like `number`) for example. So you don't want to accept those values in your function anyways!
The second issue (the missing `: string`) does make sense as well, since you're implementing the interface with this specific signature. So only `string` or a subtype of `string` should be allowed here.

Comment: @pascalpuetz "only Objects can be extended, not primitive types (like `number`)".  Well, you can indeed do `extends number` if you are referring to [numeric enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) or [numeric literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) or even [branded primitives](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal).

Comment: @pascalpuetz really appreciate it, it help me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// hasOwnProperty is part of "object", so we specify the Generic needs to be a subtype of Object - or rather a "non-primitive" type.
function extend<First extends object, Second extends object>(first: First, second: Second): First & Second {
    const result: Partial<First & Second> = {};
    for (const prop in first) {
        if (first.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            // TypeScript suspects an error here, that's why we need to convert to unknown first
            (result as unknown as First)[prop] = first[prop];
        }
    }
    for (const prop in second) {
        if (second.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            (result as unknown as Second)[prop] = second[prop];
        }
    }
    return result as unknown as First & Second;
}

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}

interface Loggable {
    log(name: string): void;
}

class ConsoleLogger implements Loggable {
    log(name: string) { // Implicit any, we know it needs to be of type "string" though, so we can just type it
        console.log(`Hello, I'm ${name}.`);
    }
}

const jim = extend(new Person('Jim'), ConsoleLogger.prototype);
jim.log(jim.name);
```

Comment: ops, I updated my question at the same time, and got the same code,  appreciate it!

Comment: I'd recommend `extends object` instead of `extends Object` since `Object` is [rarely what you actually mean](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#general-types).

Comment: @jcalz I used the uppercase on purpose, because it describes the functionality that is common to all JavaScript Objects. Though, lowercase would indeed be better to describe "non-primitive". I'll change that.